# Skip first row in pandas dataframe when creating list

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently creating a data frame from a specific column in my csv file. I am then creating a list from the values in the data frame, but I would look to skip over the first element in the data frame and not include it in my list. How can I go about doing that?

Here's the code that i'm using which is functioning:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None, error_bad_lines = False, usecols = [9], names =
['addresses'])
addresses = df['addresses'].tolist()
addresses = [x for x in addresses if str(x) != 'nan']
```

Comment: If your problems are NaNs, you can just use `df = df.dropna()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `indexing` `[1:]` - select all values excluding first:

```
addresses = [x for x in addresses[1:] if str(x) != 'nan']
```

Or:

```
addresses = df.loc[1:, 'addresses'].tolist()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'addresses':[4,8,7]})
print (df)
   addresses
0          4
1          8
2          7

addresses = df.loc[1:, 'addresses'].tolist()
print (addresses)
[8, 7]
```

Another solution, thanks [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559805/skip-first-row-in-pandas-dataframe-when-creating-list/39559825?noredirect=1#comment66430370_39559825):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""10
20
30
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=[0], names=['addresses'])
print (df)
   addresses
0         20
1         30
```

Comment: Also, you could skip the first row during reading itself by providing `skiprows=[0]`.